# Python - comparing columns in 2 files and returning merged output

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, multiple-columns, string-matching

I have a seemingly simple problem but have been stuck on it for too long now. I would like to compare two files (format shown below)

```
> file1
20  246057  0.28    68363   0   A
20  246058  0.28    68396   T   C
20  246059  0.28    76700   A   G
20  246060  0.28    76771   T   C
20  246061  0.28    76915   0   A

> file2
112879285   R   68303   20
200068921   M   68319   20
200257910   K   68336   20
200192457   W   68363   20
138777928   Y   68396   20
```

I want to compare file1 column 0 and 3 with file2 column 2 and 3 and if they match, I want to output the rest of the information for matching rows from both files as follows:

```
> desired output
20  246057  0.28    68363   0   A   200192457   W
20  246058  0.28    68396   T   C   138777928   Y
```

This is the code I have up to this point, I have tried several variations of this and many of the suggestions on here but I'm still stuck as to how to get the corresponding info from file1. Most of the things I try result in a repeat of the last line in file1 for every match.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

data2 = []
output = open("output.txt","w")

with open("file1.txt", "rb") as in_file1, open("file2.txt","rb") as in_file2:
    reader1 = csv.reader((in_file1), delimiter="\t")
    for row1 in reader1:
        y1 = row1[0], row1[3]
        data2.append(tuple(y1))
        y = row1
    reader2 = csv.reader((in_file2), delimiter="\t")
    for row2 in reader2:
        z = row2[-1], row2[2]
        if tuple(z) in data2:
            out = "\t".join(row2)
            output.write(out+"\n")
```

The part I am struggling with is getting the output from file1, after parsing. So I am currently ending up with the result below, but I also want the corresponding info for these rows from file1:

```
> current output
200192457   W   68363   20
138777928   Y   68396   20
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you! (I am using python 2.7)

Comment: Use a dict with tuple keys?

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example? I am quite new to programming sorry

Comment: Yes, I gave you an example. As a matter of fact, I gave you a fully working version of the program as the example. :)

Comment: Sorry it appears my connection is slow, will check it out now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution written from scratch by me:

```
f1 = file("file1.txt")
f2 = file("file2.txt")
d = {}
while True:
  line = f1.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 = line.split()
  d[(c0,c3)] = (c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
while True:
  line = f2.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  c0,c1,c2,c3 = line.split()
  if (c3,c2) in d:
    vals = d[(c3,c2)]
    print c3,vals[1],vals[2],vals[3],vals[4],vals[5],c0,c1
```

It reads the first file, and stores the values into a `dict` using `tuple` keys. Then it reads the second file, and checks if the `tuple` key exists in the dictionary. If so, it prints all of the data.

Note that you have to remember to close the files too in a final working version of the program. For brevity, I left out the rows to close the files.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly, I hadn't ever thought of using a dictionary with tuple keys. Great idea! I did have the file.close() in my script but didn't include them, thanks for the clarity :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice use case for [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join), [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk), and [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
$ join -11 -24 file1 file2 | awk '$4 == $9 { }' | cut -d' ' -f1-8
```

Output:

```
20 246057 0.28 68363 0 A 200192457 W
20 246058 0.28 68396 T C 138777928 Y
```

Explanation:

1. Join the two files `file1` and `file2` on the first (`-11`) and fourth (`-24`) field.
2. Filter only those lines where the 4th and the 9th field are equal (`$4 == $9`); print these lines (`{ }`).
3. From these lines print only the 1st to 8th field (`-f1-8`).

Comment: This didn't work for me, I don't get any output. Would you please be able to explain what each bit means? Sorry for the nag, I'm not too familiar with these commands but a one liner is always a bonus!

Comment: Sorry I see the explanation now!

Comment: I don't think this works for me because I would want to join the two files on both fields 1 and 4 and also fields 4 and 3. Whereas when they are joined by just field 1 and 4 these are identical anyway so I believe that some of the matching values in field 4 and 9 won't be on the same row, if that makes sense?

Comment: That's why in the second step I use `awk` to filter only those lines where the second pair of fields are equal. The output in my answer is exactly what you get when running the command.

Comment: That's strange as I still get no output :( I think it might be something to do with piping commands on my computer, but I will keep trying! I tried the join command by itself and it joins every possible combination which is what I was confused about so I understand now. Thank you very much for the answer and explanation!

Comment: @Tichodroma You need to remove the empty braces in the AWK command, otherwise the output will always be empty, as reported by user3078840. So, the working command is: `join -11 -24 file1 file2 | awk '$4 == $9' | cut -d' ' -f1-8`. Alternatively you can avoid the last `cut` command: `join -11 -24 file1 file2 | awk '$4 == $9 {$9 = $10 = ""; print}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to following, you actually need to store row1 for which you get the match in file2:

```
with open("file1.txt", "rb") as in_file1, open("file2.txt","rb") as in_file2:
reader1 = csv.reader((in_file1), delimiter="\t")
for row1 in reader1:
    y1 = row1[0], row1[3]
    reader2 = csv.reader((in_file2), delimiter="\t")
    for row2 in reader2:
        z = row2[-1], row2[2]
        if tuple(z) in [tuple(y1)]:
              out = "\t".join(row1)
              output.write(out+"\n")    
              out = "\t".join(row2)
              output.write(out+"\n")
```

Comment: Where you have 'out =' twice is that meant to be output for row1 and then output for row2 written to the output file? I changed it but it only wrote one match to the output file when there are 2.