# ValueError: too many values to unpack (while using a dict with tuple keys)

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, multiple-columns, valueerror

I want to compare two .txt files. The first file is a "key" with three values separated by tabs (i.e. "Item Number" "Response" and "Code"). The second file contains two values separated by tabs ("Item Number" and "Response"). I need my program to search the first file, find any matching "Item Number/Response" pairs with the second file, then output the correct "Code." If there is not a match, then I would like the output to just be a space (" "). I am not a programmer, but figuring this out would greatly decrease time I spend on certain tasks at work.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278265/python-comparing-columns-in-2-files-and-returning-merged-output) to be helpful in setting up my code. I want to accomplish the same thing.

```
file 1, "Key.txt":  
1   dog C  
2   cat C  
3   bird    C  
4   pig C  
5   horse   C  
1   cat Sem  
2   bat TA  
3   animal  Super  
4   panda   M  
5   pencil  U  

file2, "Uncoded.txt":  
4   pig  
3   animal  
5   bird  
2   bat  
2   cat  
0   
1   fluffy  
0   dog  
1   

desired output:  
4   pig  C  
3   animal  Super  
5   bird    
2   bat  TA  
2   cat  C  
0     
1   fluffy    
0   dog    
1
```

Below is the code I have:

```
f1 = open("Key.txt")  
f2 = open("Uncoded.txt")    
d = {}  

while True:  
    line = f1.readline()  
    if not line:  
        break  
    c0,c1,c2 = line.split('\t')  
    d[(c0,c1)] = (c0,c1,c2)  
while True:  
    line = f2.readline()  
    if not line:  
        break  
    c0,c1 = line.split('\t')  
    if (c0,c1) in d:  
        vals = d[(c0,c1)]  
        print (c0, c1, vals[1])  

f1.close()  
f2.close()
```

If I try to separate the lines with tabs ('\t') then I get a ValueError: too many values to unpack at the line "c0,c1,c2 = line.split('\t')"

Thanks so much for any insight or help!

Comment: if there's an empty line (in the end for instance), this could go undetected, but `split` returns empty list: doesn't unpack very well. split, check length of your list, then unpack.

Comment: You have lines with differing numbers of items, but you've got a set number of variables `c0,c1,c2` so anytime the number of items doesn't equal your number of variables, you're going to get an error.

Comment: Would y'all recommend approaching the problem with something other than dictionary and tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that one of the lines in one of your files doesn't have the number of items on it that you expect. A possible cause of that is an extra newline (probably at the end of the file). Python will see that as a line with only a newline character in it after the last *real* line. Your logic will fail when it can't split the empty line into three parts.

One way to work around the issue is to split into a single variable, without unpacking the values. Then you can check how many items were split, and only go on with the unpacking if it is the expected amount:

```
while True:  
    line = f1.readline()  
    if not line:  
        break  
    vals = line.split('\t')  # don't unpack immediately
    if len(val) == 3:        # check you got the expected number of items
        c0, c1, c2 = vals    # unpack only if it will work
        d[(c0,c1)] = (c0,c1,c2)
    else:
        print("got unexpected number of values: {}".format(vals) # if not, report the error
```

It's unrelated to your error, but you can simplify your loop quite a bit if you want to, by using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. File objects are iterable, yielding the lines of the file (just like you get from `readline()`. The nicest thing about it is that you don't need to look for the end of the file yourself, the iteration just ends when the file is exhausted:

```
for line in f1:    # this does the same thing as the first four lines in the code above
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for your insight. I used the simplified `for` loop and also wrote some code to help python read my text files the way they are set up. It's working now! Thanks so much!